# Export to PDF function dont give option to Save Or Open on Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, pdf-generation

```
public string ExportToPDF_ManageDefects(bool isEmailPDF, DataTable dt, string headerText)
    {

        string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
        string pdfName = string.Empty;
        //string headerText = string.Empty;
        //Create document
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);
        PdfWriter writer = null;
        FileStream fs =null;
        try
        {
            if (!isEmailPDF)
            {
                pdfName = headerText+"_" + timeStamp + ".pdf";
                fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/PDFReport/"+pdfName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
                writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
            }
            else
            {
                writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
            }

            DataTable filteredData = dt;// (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["filteredData"];
            document.Open();
            document.Add(CreatePDFTable_HeaderImage());
            document.Add(CreatePDFTable_HeaderText(headerText));
            document.Add(CreatePDFTable_SearchText(headerText));
            document.Add(CreatePDFTable_BodyDataTable(filteredData));
            document.Add(CreatePDFTable_Footer());
            document.Close();

            if (isEmailPDF)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/PDF";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition:", "attachment; filename='"+headerText+"'" + timeStamp + ".pdf");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>window.open('"+headerText+"_" + timeStamp + ".pdf',target='new');</script>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return pdfName;
```

In my case i am trying to popup Save or Open window on browser, Where as the physical file is saved in above said path.

The requirement is to open in new tab or else at least it should ask for Save or Open

Also i have used
response.End(); // -- Have tried to changing this line to -->

HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); // -- This does not throw the exception but don't work for me.

The parameters are as follows : IsEmail = False, headerText = GroupDetails_201666185411, dt = Set of DataTable.

[image]

Comment: Kindly suggest Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my html page a just added this code and my work was done.

```
<Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPDF" />
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCSV" />
        </Triggers>
```

After that i have written the JavaScript code to open my PDF file in new tab.

```
function NewWindow() {
        document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
    }
```

And called the same function on my button event.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPDF" runat="server" CssClass="BigBtn" OnClientClick="NewWindow();"></asp:Button>
```

Thanks all =)